# MYSQL GROUP BY two columns in chat

Tags: mysql, group-by, row, chat, concatenation

I'm setting up a chat-service.
The table for my messages is created as followed:

```
CREATE TABLE message (
    fromId int NOT NULL,
    toId int NOT NULL,
    message text NOT NULL,
    timestamp timestamp NOT NULL,
    toRead int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (fromId) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (toId) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As a user I should get all other users I already chatted with. Therefore I create an sql-statement:

```
SELECT u.name, u.surname, u.id, m.toRead, m.timestamp, m.fromId, m.toId 
FROM message m, user_informations u 
WHERE (m.toId = '2' AND m.fromId = u.id) OR (m.fromId = '2' AND m.toId = u.id) 
GROUP BY concat(m.fromId, m.toId OR m.toId, m.fromId) 
ORDER BY m.timestamp LIMIT 10;
```

It works as long as one users only writes the other. If both have written each other I get two returned columns

```
'Peter','Tester','1','0','2015-07-27 16:10:11','1','2'
'Peter','Tester','1','0','2015-07-27 17:14:22','2','1'
```

because `fromId` in first result is other than in second and same with `toId`.

How can I get the statement to return only one row?

Comment: Get rid of the OR statement `(m.toId = '2' AND m.fromId = u.id)`  you should only be looking for those FROM the logged in user.  or define "chatted with" if someone sent something to me and I didn't send anything back.. I've not"Chatted" with them... they sent something to me  If you want those as well then you get duplicates such as this, the only way to eliminate them would be to not group by both.

Comment: Can you post a larger sample of input rows for us to test?  Using `LEAST(), GREATEST()` on the from/to columns will probably solve this.

Comment: I need the `(m.toId = '2' AND m.fromId = u.id)` statement, because otherwise I won't get the chat if only I sent a message and didn't received any

Comment: Ok, so your definition of chat is anything you send to and anything you receive from uni directional.  bi-directional isn't necessary.

Comment: `LEAST()` really works. thank you